# Iteration for Recurrent Problem with Python

Tags: python, iteration

I am asked to find the 30th of a recurrence series, following the equation `x(n) = 2*x(n-1) - x(n-2)` for n >= 3, and `x(1) = 0` and `x(2) = 1`.

Following the logic of fibonacci iteration, I have come up with the following code:

```
def loop(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(30):
        a, b = b, 2 * b - a
    return a
```

Suiting in `loop(30)`, I am returned 30, but I know mathematically that the answer should be 29. The code seems to be going one step ahead. Can anyone help point out what is incorrect in my code?

Comment: If you start with the 1st element, and advance 30 elements, which element do you end up with?

Comment: Are you not supposed to be using recursion to solve this since that is what the question asked for

Comment: 0, 1 are the X[0, 1] - first and second sequence numbers...so... array is zero-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only run the loop `n - 1` times. Because the assignment `a = 0` initializes `x1`. Then after each loop, `a` is assigned by the next value (from `x2`)

```py
def loop(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        a, b = b, 2*b - a
    return a
    
print(loop(30))
# 29
```

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that for the first time value of a=1 ( a=b=1;), According to the condition value of a is incremented by 1 ( a=b when b=2*b-1) so the output will be n on next nth iterations.;